# #1227 - Acceso denegado; necesita (al menos uno de) los privilegios SUPER para esta operación en 10hosting?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo un problemas en mi base de datos que subí a un hosting gratuito, el problema esta en que cuando quiero integrar mis planificadores de tareas para que se ejecuten no me deja instalarlos y ni siquiera me deja activar el planificador no se que pase ya agregue un usuario con privilegios para esa base ya lo hice con el usuario que estaba designado y tampoco alguien que pueda ayudarme seria lo mejor y gracias de antemano!

[image: Aqui esta el error que me marca]

Comment: Saludos mira en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html las consideraciones y formas de hacerlo; aunque en hosting compartidos por lo regular hay opciones que no permiten habilitarlas o cambiarlas por seguridad y/o políticas.

Comment: muchas gracias aun que ya lei la doc de planificadores y aun no lo consigo :( @Roberto Leon Oramas